# function not going past if statements in discord bot

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a discord bot to help with trivia for a group of friends. I am using python and when I put print statements to try and debug I notice that the function does not go into or past the if statements in the code below:

The issue is within checkPointAvailable. I am not super familiar with python (have only taken one 1 credit class) and very unfamiliar with discord.py and APIs and would love learn what my issue may be. Thanks!

```
@bot.command(name='answer')
async def answer(ctx, points:int, *args):
    if(globalSubmission == 0):
        await ctx.send(f'Submissions are not currently open!')
        return
    error = checkPointAvailable(ctx, points)
    answer = " ".join(args[:])
    name = findPlayer(ctx.author.id)
    correct = checkAnswer(globalCorrectAnswer, answer)
    addAnswer(globalDate, globalRound, globalQuestionNO, name, answer, points, correct)
    await ctx.send(f'Submitted "{answer}" for {points} points for Round {globalRound}, Question {globalQuestionNO}')


def checkPointAvailable(ctx, points):
    name = findPlayer(ctx.author.id)
    print(globalRound)
    if((globalRound < 4) and (globalRound > 0)):
        print('In first if')
        if(points != 2 or points != 4 or points != 6):
            print('In second if')
            #ctx.send(f'Inelligible point value, please use 2, 4, or 6 points.')
            return 0
    print('post if statements')
```

Comment: If the first `if` statement in `checkPointAvailable` isn't being entered, that's because `globalRound` isn't between 0 and 4 (exclusive). Note that the second `if` statement, `points != 2 or points != 4 or points != 6`, would _always_ be entered and you're probably looking for `and` rather than `or` there.

Comment: That second point is very valid, but even if globalRound is between 0 and 4 it doesn't enter the statement, and even if it wasn't shouldn't it still hit the print('post if statements') and print that to console?

Comment: Are you, per chance, using an exception handler for this command? If so it might be that you are dealing with a silent error.